# How to exclude a tag when web scraping

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am having a crack at using Python 3.8 and BeautifulSoup to scrape a web page and I have come across an issue I haven't been able to resolve.  The page I am scraping has two similar div tags which both contain an id value, however one also contains an additional class container:

For example, the first tag returns: ; and the second tag returns .

I can find the tags using "page = soup.find_all('div', { "id" : "race-1"})", but this returns both divs.  Is there way that I can find just the div that contains ""?  I only want this one, as the format of the data within this div tag is much easier for me to work with.

I have pulled out the following relevant portion of the code I am working with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import bleach
import os.path
from os import path

def scrape(racedate, location, races, pageurl):
    if path.exists("ResultsData.csv"):
        f = csv.writer(open('ResultsData.csv', 'a', newline='')) #Use 
    else:
        f = csv.writer(open('ResultsData.csv', 'a', newline='')) #Use 
        f.writerow(['RaceDate', 'RaceLocation', 'RaceNumber', 'RaceName', 'Distance', 'RaceClass', 'PrizeMoney', 'RaceSplits', 'Place', 'BoxNo', 'DogName', 'Trainer', 'Time', 'Margin', 'Split', 'InRun', 'Weight', 'Sire', 'Dam', 'SPrice'])

    page = requests.get(pageurl)

    # Create a BeautifulSoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a") 

    raceid = "race-1"
    page = soup.find_all('div', { "id" : raceid})
    file1.write(str(page))


scrape('2019/11/16', 'ipswich', '10', 'https://www.thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/results/ipswich/68024')
```

I'm not a developer by any stretch of the imagination, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share an example of the two divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `find_all` call to filter by css class as well as tag id

```
    raceid = "race-1"
    page = soup.find_all('div', id=raceid, class_='')
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: Thanks heaps for this answer, it has worked perfectly!

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I wanted to select all divs where id-raceid and class="anything but xyz", can this be done?  For example I want to select all divs that have a class equal to blue or red or yellow but not purple.

Comment: Yes you can make more complex conditions for your filtering, check the doc page here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class and look at the `has_six_characters` example, you can use any function you want to return a boolean value based on the given class.  When in doubt, read the docs